# Updating one element after another updates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a page in which one element ('.item--itemprice') updates its text through another function that I'd prefer not to touch. What I'd like to do is get another element ('.header--itemprice') to update so that its text matches the first element.

Unfortunately, it seems that handler below is acting faster than the updating function. As a result, the header either stays with the previous text or changes to a blank string. Is there a way to delay the final line below until after the first element is finished updating?

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
   const headPrice = document.querySelector('.header--itemprice');
   const lowerPrice = document.querySelector('span.item--itemprice');
   const $lowerText = $(lowerPrice).text();
   $(headPrice).text($lowerText);
});
```

Here's the preexisting function:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#txtQuantity, .ProductGroupItemQuantity').blur(updatePrice);
});

function updatePrice() {
  var itemPriceEl = $('.item--itemprice');
  var itemCountEl = $('#txtQuantity');
  var groupUpdateEl = $('#lnkProductGroupUpdatePrice');
  var groupPriceEl = $('.pdetail--price-total');
  var totalPriceEl = $('.ProductDetailsPricing');
  var itemPrice = moneyToNumber(itemPriceEl.text());
  var itemCount = moneyToNumber(itemCountEl.val());
  var itemTotalPrice = itemCount * itemPrice;
  var groupTotalPrice = 0;

  // Trigger Group Update
  groupUpdateEl.click();
  groupTotalPrice = moneyToNumber(groupPriceEl.text());

  // Calculate Total Price
  totalPriceEl.text('Total: $' + Number(groupTotalPrice + itemTotalPrice) / 100);
}

/*$('select').on('change', function() {
  const headPrice = document.querySelector('.header--itemprice');
  const lowerPrice = document.querySelector('span.item--itemprice');
  const $lowerText = $(lowerPrice).text();
    $(headPrice).text($lowerText);
});*/

function moneyToNumber(moneyEl) {
  try {
    return Number(moneyEl.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"").replace(/\D/g,''));
  } catch (err) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the corresponding HTML and the other function.

Comment: why do you use jQuery, the vanilla querySelector and es6?

Comment: when does that function you are not showing us, updates the first element? They should do it almost at the same time.
Is it triggered by select change event? If so, you can call the function above after your mysterious function.

Comment: Added the rest of the scripts for the page. Is there a convenient way to add the html (it's over 400 lines)? Sorry, new here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to touch the other function at all and assuming it is also being called on the change event of select. A really hacky way could be, something like this -

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
setTimeout (function()
{
   const headPrice = document.querySelector('.header--itemprice');
   const lowerPrice = document.querySelector('span.item--itemprice');
   const $lowerText = $(lowerPrice).text();
   $(headPrice).text($lowerText);
}, 0);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned. I did try that - no luck.

Comment: Is the other function also being called on change of select ?

Comment: I'm honestly having trouble parsing the other functions. I've added them in the original now

Answer (score 0):

In that case, the better way is changing the function, you can even trigger a event when the function is executed and watch this event to trigger the other function to change the element ('.header--itemprice')

Comment: Sounds great. Could you go into a little more detail on how this could look?

Comment: you watch the event to update the value
$( ".item--itemprice" ).on( "updatePrice", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert("Price was updated");
});

inside the function you trigger
$( ".item--itemprice" ).trigger( "updatePrice", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );